# Can't type '?' in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I can't get Notepad++ to let me input a question mark (?). I can shift + any other key to get the upper character. I can go to any other program -- notepad, Word, this text box, etc, and it works. I can also run Npp under my admin account and use the Shift + '/ ?' key to get the ?.

I can also open the character panel from the Edit menu and insert the question mark from that.

I was running 5.9.3 but I upgraded to 6.2.3 to see if it was a version issue, but that didn't fix the issue. I also tried uninstalling/re-installing.

Did I somehow set something that disallowed me to enter a '?' with the keyboard? I've looked through all of the settings but I can't seem to find where I might do that.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stackoverflow.  Try asking it on http://superuser.com

Comment: Accidentally set a keyboard shortcut? Global for Notepad++ or for some of it's macroses?

Comment: @Madbreaks: No, it isn't.

Comment: @BoltClock Looks like at least 5 people disagree with you.  I personally don't see this is (was) a programming-related question.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a *good* SU question either, but it's certainly off-topic here.

Comment: have you tried setting your default encoding back to ansi?

Comment: This does not fall under 'software tools commonly used by programmers' in the FAQ? I'm trying to write some Regular Expressions and ? is a pretty important character there.

Comment: @MichaelJCox: Of course it does, as much as questions about vim, emacs, Visual Studio, Xcode, Eclipse... anyway, have you tried fully uninstalling then reinstalling?

Comment: @MichaelJCox check to see if you don't have any macros mapped to `?` (Macro menu > modify shortcut delete macro)

Comment: @BoltClock, I did. I'm still seeing the same issue.

Comment: @sachleen got it. There was a macro mapped to 'Shift + /'. Thank You!

Comment: @sachleen, if you want to make your comment an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: FYI, Uninstall/Reinstall didn't wipe out the macros file (shortcuts.xml) or the directory in which that was found (AppData/Roaming/Notepad++). That's why the problem macro persisted on my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you don't have any macros mapped to `?`

You can do this by going to the "Macro" menu and selecting "Modify shortcut/delete macro"

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, In my case the propriety of the file was the problem.
The file had the property "Read-only", and that is why I couldn't edit her.